# Which package to upgrade psql client?

Tags: redhat, postgresql, psql

I have updated my Postgres install from 8.4 to 9.3.

Now when I log onto the server with the initial command

```
 sudo -u postgres psql template1
```

I get the following error

```
psql (8.4.18, server 9.3.5)
WARNING: psql version 8.4, server version 9.3.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.
```

What package do I need to install / upgrade to get psql to 9.4 version? (On red hat 6)

Comment: You forgot to explain exactly how you "updated" PostgreSQL.

Comment: installed it via yum using the postgress repositories
http://yum.postgresql.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've installed the new server, the new clients are installed too - they're a dependency of the server.

Redhat systems now use an "alternatives" mechanism similar to Debian. You'll find that `/usr/bin/psql` is a symlink pointing to `/etc/alternatives/pgsql-psql` which is in turn a symlink to the default `psql`.

You can use the `update-alternatives` command to switch default clients - see its `--help`. Or you can just:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/psql
```

directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `whereis psql` command to find out, where `psql` binary/symlink is located

Use the next command to rename `psql` binary (you could remove it later):

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/psql /usr/bin/psql.old
```

Then use the next command to create symlink for a current `psql` binary:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config pgsql-psql

There is 1 program that provides 'pgsql-psql'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/psql

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

As a result:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql
psql (9.5.22)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```